# If $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{ny_i+1}=1$, then $\prod\limits_{i=1}^{n+1}y_i\geq 1$?

Tags: inequality

Let $y_1,\ldots,y_{n+1}$ be positive real numbers satisfying $\displaystyle{\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} \frac{1}{ny_i+1}=1}$.

Is it true that $y_1y_2\cdots y_{n+1}\geq 1$?

Added: can we determine this inequality in terms of high-school math? (e.g. Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, arithmetic mean-geometric mean inequality)

Comment: Could you please consider using somewhat more descriptive titles? I'm just guessing you're the same person as the "Mark Jin" who asked [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46900/on-the-inequality). Also, what do you want to achieve with these inequalities? No offense, I'm just curious.

Comment: I'm same person. I just want to prove $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1}\frac{1}{ny_i+1}=1$ implies $y_1\cdots y_{n+1}\geq 1$. From some Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, I can get $y_1+\cdots y_{n+1}\geq n+1$ and $1/y_1+1/y_2\cdots/y_{n+1}\geq n+1$. That's why I asked [that question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/46900/on-the-inequality) yesterday. And I'm unregistered user hence I should use another name.

Comment: @Jonas: I would prefer that `\displaystyle` was not used in question titles. It is still typeset as large inline text, and on the front page I feel it looks rather conspicuous.

Comment: @Rahul: I agree with that. Is this better, or still conspicuous?

Comment: @Theo: Looks good to me. Thanks!

Comment: @Rahul, Theo: I agree that it is much better now, thank you.

Comment: The cases $n=1,n=2$ are true.

Comment: @Mark: please register your account. You won't have any trouble with logging back in that way.

Answer (score 5):

Let $a_i = \frac{1}{ny_i + 1}$, then $\sum a_i = 1$, $0 < a_i < 1$ for all $i$, and you want to show that

$$\prod_i \left(\frac{1}{a_i} - 1\right) \ge n^{n+1}$$

Clear denominator, and use the sum condition, you want to show

$$\prod_i (a_1 + \cdots + \hat{a_i} + \cdots + a_{n+1}) \ge n^{n+1} \prod a_i$$

(the hat means I ignore that term in summation) This follows from applying AM-GM for each thing on the left.

Answer (score 4):

You could have a look at [Lagrange multiplier method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange_multiplier).

**Edit** Here is a proof using only convexity and basic calculus.

*First case: $y_i\ge1/n$ for every $i$*

Consider the function $u$ defined by 
$$u(t)=\frac1{1+n\mathrm{e}^t}.$$
Computing the second derivative of $u$, one sees that $u$ is convex on the domain where $n\mathrm{e}^t\ge1$. Hence, if $n+1$ numbers $t_i$ are such that $n\mathrm{e}^{t_i}\ge1$ for every $i$, then 
$$
u(t_1)+\cdots+u(t_{n+1})\ge(n+1)u\left(\frac{t_1+\cdots+t_{n+1}}{n+1}\right).
$$
Assume that $y_i\ge1/n$ for every $i$ and apply the inequality above to $t_i=\log y_i$, then the LHS is by hypothesis $1$ and
$t_1+\cdots+t_{n+1}=\log(y_1\cdots y_{n+1})$ hence the RHS is 
$$
(n+1)u\left(\frac{\log(y_1\cdots y_{n+1})}{n+1}\right).
$$ 
Since $(n+1)u(t)\le1$ if and only if $t\ge0$, this shows that $\log(y_1\cdots y_{n+1})\ge0$ and we are done.

*Second case: $y_i<1/n$ for some $i$*

Note that this can happen at most for one index $i$ and assume for example that $y_1<1/n$, then $y_i\ge1/n$ for every $i\ne1$ and $y_i>1/n$ for at least one index $i\ne1$. Assume for instance that $y_2>1/n$. Define a deformation $(y_1(z),y_2(z))$ of $(y_1,y_2)$ for every small enough nonnegative $z$ by $y_1(z)=y_1+z$ and
$$
\frac1{1+ny_1(z)}+\frac1{1+ny_2(z)}=\frac1{1+ny_1}+\frac1{1+ny_2}.
$$
Then the product $y_1(z)y_2(z)$ is a decreasing function of $z$ as long as $y_1(z)\le1/n\le y_2(z)$ (the proof is in the addendum below) hence the result holds for $z=0$ as soon as it holds for such a given positive $z$.

If this is enough to move the value of $y_1$ up to $1/n$, the proof is complete. Otherwise this means that $y_1(z)<1/n=y_2(z)$ for a given $z$. Apply the same procedure to this new $y_1$ and to another $y_i$ such that $y_i>1/n$. After at most $n$ steps, one gets a collection $(\bar y_i)$ which still satisfies the hypothesis of the post and such that $\bar y_i\ge1/n$ for every $i$. Furthermore,
$$
y_1\cdots y_{n+1}\ge \bar y_1\cdots \bar y_{n+1}.
$$ 
The first case shows that $\bar y_1\cdots \bar y_{n+1}\ge1$, hence we are done.

*Addendum: the function $z\mapsto y_1(z)y_2(z)$ is decreasing*

Differentiating, one sees that one should show that
$$
y_2(z)(1+ny_1(z))^2< y_1(z)(1+ny_2(z))^2.
$$
Using the fact that $y_2(z)> y_1(z)$, this is equivalent to $n^2y_1(z)y_2(z)> 1$, which in turn is equivalent to
$$
\frac1{1+ny_1(z)}+\frac1{1+ny_2(z)}< 1,
$$
hence the assertion holds.

Comment: I want use only high-school level method. (e.g. Cauchy-Schwarz inequality)

Answer (score 0):

In the case $n=1$, check it yourself that you get $y_1y_2=1$.

In the case $n=2$ the relation translates to $8y_1y_2y_3=2(y_1+y_2+y_3)+2 \geq 6 \sqrt[3]{y_1y_2y_3}+2$. Denote $\sqrt[3]{y_1y_2y_3}=k$.

We have $8k^3-6k-2 \geq 0$ which is equivalent to $(k-1)(8k^2+8k+2) \geq 0$. Since the second factor is positive for $k>0$ it follows that $k \geq 1$.

Maybe something similar can be tried for $n$ greater than $4$.

[edit] The same reasoning, with a greater deal of computations works for $n=4$ too.

Lagrange multipliers method gives us that the optimal value for the product is obtained for equal values of $y_i$, and those values are equal to $1$. Therefore the inequality $y_1...y_{n+1}\geq 1$ is true.